# invalid read data from nand flash

Tags: stm32f4, nand-flash, fsmc

I want to use a nand flash ic with part number of K9F1G08U0C and connect it to a stm32f429igt6 microcontroller.

**Although I can read the ID of this nand successfully but the written data and read back, are not the same.- I just read 0x31 -**

I can also see the control signals with my logic analyzer and they are all acting as the datasheet says.

here is my test codes:

```
{
    static NAND_AddressTypeDef WriteReadAddr;
    static NAND_IDTypeDef NAND_ID;
    static uint8_t TxBuffer [2048];
    static uint8_t RxBuffer [2048];

    HAL_NAND_Reset(&hnand1);
    HAL_Delay(100);

    /* Read the NAND memory ID */
    HAL_NAND_Read_ID(&hnand1, &NAND_ID);
    HAL_Delay(100);

    /* Fill the buffer to send */
    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++ )
    {
        RxBuffer[i] = 0;
    }

    /* Fill the buffer to send */
    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++ )
    {
        TxBuffer[i] = i;
    }

    /* NAND memory address to write to */
    WriteReadAddr.Plane = 0;
    WriteReadAddr.Block = 2;
    WriteReadAddr.Page = 0;

    /* Erase the NAND first Block */
    if( HAL_NAND_Erase_Block(&hnand1, &WriteReadAddr) != HAL_OK)
    {

        while(1);
    }
    HAL_Delay(100);


    /* Write data to FMC NAND memory */
    if(HAL_NAND_Write_Page(&hnand1, &WriteReadAddr, TxBuffer, 1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        while(1);
    }
    HAL_Delay(100);

    /* Read data from FMC NAND memory */
    if(HAL_NAND_Read_Page(&hnand1, &WriteReadAddr, RxBuffer, 1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        while(1);
    }

    /* check date */
    if(memcmp(TxBuffer,RxBuffer,sizeof(TxBuffer)) == 0 )
        printf("\r\n\r\n NandFlash Read Write Test OK\r\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\r\n\r\n NandFlash Read Write False\r\n");
        while(1);
    }

}
```

and as you can see I use the hal nand flash library.

Here is how I init fmc peripheral:

```
static void MX_FMC_Init(void)
    {
      FMC_NAND_PCC_TimingTypeDef ComSpaceTiming;
      FMC_NAND_PCC_TimingTypeDef AttSpaceTiming;

      /** Perform the NAND2 memory initialization sequence
      */
      hnand2.Instance = FMC_NAND_DEVICE;
      /* hnand2.Init */
      hnand2.Init.NandBank = FMC_NAND_BANK2;
      hnand2.Init.Waitfeature = FMC_NAND_PCC_WAIT_FEATURE_ENABLE;
      hnand2.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FMC_NAND_PCC_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_8;
      hnand2.Init.EccComputation = FMC_NAND_ECC_DISABLE;
      hnand2.Init.ECCPageSize = FMC_NAND_ECC_PAGE_SIZE_256BYTE;
      hnand2.Init.TCLRSetupTime = 8;
      hnand2.Init.TARSetupTime = 8;
      /* hnand2.Config */
      hnand2.Config.PageSize = 2048;
      hnand2.Config.SpareAreaSize = 64;
      hnand2.Config.BlockSize = 64;
      hnand2.Config.BlockNbr = 1024;
      hnand2.Config.PlaneNbr = 1;
      hnand2.Config.PlaneSize = 1024;
      hnand2.Config.ExtraCommandEnable = DISABLE;
      /* ComSpaceTiming */
      ComSpaceTiming.SetupTime = 0xF5;
      ComSpaceTiming.WaitSetupTime = 0xF3;
      ComSpaceTiming.HoldSetupTime = 0xF2;
      ComSpaceTiming.HiZSetupTime = 0xF5;
      /* AttSpaceTiming */
      AttSpaceTiming.SetupTime = 0xF5;
      AttSpaceTiming.WaitSetupTime = 0xF3;
      AttSpaceTiming.HoldSetupTime = 0xF2;
      AttSpaceTiming.HiZSetupTime = 0xF5;

      if (HAL_NAND_Init(&hnand2, &ComSpaceTiming, &AttSpaceTiming) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler( );
      }

    }
```

And if you need furthur information you can download the whole project here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ro2nl2sssghympi/test_nand_flash.rar?dl=0

Comment: Questions here must present the core of the problem within the body of the post itself, links are only for supplemental detail.  A question posted here must make sense standing on its own, so you will need to use the `edit` button to present key information here - for example, explain the operations you conduct and what you do read.  Did you erase first?   Without improvement this question is likely to end up closed.

Comment: You might first try just erasing and then reading and hexdumping what you get to see if the value is what it should be post erase.

Comment: I test it but again I just get 0x31 in RxBuffer.